# Image Downsampling by Large Factor without Artefacts

Tags: python, image, image-resizing

Is there a python image resizing algorithm that can scale colour images by large factors with minimal artefacts? For example, from 1234x1234 to 32x32. The goal is to be able to produce high-quality 32x32 images like those in [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) from very large images.

OpenCV image resizing algorithms (linear, bicubic, lancsoz, area, etc.) are insufficient as they produce lots of artefacts. Perhaps something like the [magic kernel method](http://www.johncostella.com/magic/)?

Comment: Bilinear should produce a slightly soft image, but with no ringing, which I guess would be good for ML applications. You'd get slight ringing with lanczos I suppose. Neither should have any aliasing. Could you explain what kinds of artifact you want to minimise?

Comment: Generally, you should perform a low pass filter before downsampling to avoid aliasing . I think a Gaussian blur with sigma=sqrt(n), where n is downsampling factor, should do the trick.

Comment: @jcupitt I'm most concerned by aliasing. Typically, aliasing is reduced by low-pass filter; however, I have been unable to find a fully optimised algorithm available in python e.g. magic kernel resampling.

Comment: You shouldn't need a low-pass filter -- all downsizers I know will do this for you. They compute a kernel large enough to make sure there's no aliasing. I added an answer using pillow. Use pillow-simd and it should be extremely fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) resize with `Image.LANCZOS` will use a large kernel and won't suffer from aliasing.

For example, wikipedia have this Chicago skyline:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chicago_Skyline_Hi-Res.jpg

It's a large image with a difficult aspect ratio, large flat areas, and plenty of repeating fine detail.

This program:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
target_size = 256.0
horizontal_scale = im.size[0] / target_size
vertical_scale = im.size[1] / target_size
scale = max(horizontal_scale, vertical_scale)
new_size = (int(im.size[0] / scale), int(im.size[1] / scale))
im = im.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Run on the original 14696x1779 pixel image makes this result:

[image]

I made a blow-up of the centre area:

[image]

You can see there's no aliasing, but there is slight ringing, as you'd expect from Lanczos.

If you downsize with bilinear instead (Pillow uses a triangle filter for this), you get a softer look, but no aliasing and no ringing. It might be more suitable for an ML input.

[image]

I'd be surprised if OpenCV couldn't also do this, but I don't know it well enough to suggest code.

Comment: This is an excellent, detailed answer with examples. Your comment on my opening post about kernels being large enough to minimize aliasing alleviated my concerns.